# how can i change the "full computer name" in windows 7 leaving (short) computer name untouched?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Is there a way to change "full computer name" in windows 7.
Want to leave (short) computer name untouched.
Is this possible?

Computer is not member of any domain.

Why I am asking?  I am looking for a way to give end user additional Information about his/hers pc - and I am trying to understand why there are two different fields displaying same information most of the time.

Note:  when searching the Internet 'friend' Google reports many ways to change (short) computer name, that makes it difficult to find instuctions about changing "full computer name"

Best regards

Comment: This cannot be done. The full computer name is just the "short" computer name along with the domain name. If you're not part of a domain, the full computer name is the same as the "short" one. That's why there is no option to specifically change the full computer name separately from the regular computer name.

Comment: Basically if you have a PC called EXAMPLE-PC and it is not part of a domain, it's full name is EXAMPLE-PC. If you then join it to a domain called example.com, the full name of the PC becomes EXAMPLE-PC.example.com

Comment: As n8te has said; one element is the hostname and the other elements are part of the domain name, the result is the FQDN (fully qualified domain name)

Comment: Thank You for the fast and understandable answer.  So even if there would be a (maybe tricky) way to enter the full computer name it woud be overwritten as soon as the pc joins a domain, right?

BTW, is there a way to join a fake domain named like "this is my additional Information for that pc".Domain?  Sorry for that maybe silly question (but I do not give up quickly ... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The full computer name is derived from the short one.

What you can do is, on the computer name screen click the "Change" button,
then click the "More" button, then set the
[Primary DNS suffix](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc959611.aspx)
and click OK, then reboot.

This will change the
[Fully qualified domain name (FQDN)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) of the computer and may cause problems
with the connections to other computers on the local network.
It is really only meant to be used within an Active Directory domain
and with a local DNS server.

It is there to help you enter server names locally "short" or with partial domains. For example take `ping computer-name`, where the Primary DNS suffix
is helpfully added by default before computer-name.
But it may have other negative effects that I am not aware of,
since I never tried to misconfigure a computer.

Comment: Thanks to all who answered.  I think I understand this feature now.

BTW, as I am new to here, is there a way to mark my question answered or to mark answers as helpful?  Thanks again.

Comment: Acceptance is via the V button.  Upvote via the Up arrow.